# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:Unresolved compilation problems: working with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am a begineer in selenium and trying my own after installation of eclipse, java, selenium, TestNg and started writing the below code.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>
> WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
>
> FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type
>
> at Mypackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:8)

```
package Mypackage;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "http://google.com";
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Hello";
        String actualTitle = "";
        driver.get(baseUrl);        
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)) {
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add selenium webdriver jar files to the project

right click on project-->goto build path-->configure build path-->click on "Add external jars"-->add selenium jar files from your local machine-->click ok-->now mouseover on WebDriver in your code-->click "import webdriver"--now run your code-->you will get rid of the exception.